# Email a folder/file using vbscript

Tags: shell, vbscript

Basically i want to email a file inside a folder. The file is dynamically generated after execution of some program.But the problem is how do i attach the dynamically generated file(The name changes continously

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
objMail.To = "to@gmail.com"
objMail.cc = "from@gmail.com"
objMail.Subject = "Test Mail Subject"
objMail.Body = "Test mail body"
objMail.Attachments.Add("path")
objMail.Send 
objOutlook.Quit
Set objMail = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
```

i can get the path upto the folder but how can i dyanmically choose to attach anyfile inside the folder.Can i mail the entire folder(by compressing it).If so how.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can't "email a folder". Folders are a filesystem concept, and have NO representation in email. You could maybe create a .zip or other archive of the file, which on most OS'es these days can be browsed as if they're folders.

Comment: You will have to read the contents of the folder.http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/10/20/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-files-in-a-folder-and-its-subfolders.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

theFolder = "FolderPathGoesHere"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(theFolder).Files
    SendEmail objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(objFile)
Next

Set objFSO = Nothing

Sub SendEmail(theFileName)

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    objMail.To = "to@gmail.com"
    objMail.cc = "from@gmail.com"
    objMail.Subject = "Test Mail Subject"
    objMail.Body = "Test mail body"
    objMail.Attachments.Add(theFileName)
    objMail.Send 
    objOutlook.Quit
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!.. just 1 small doubt..do i have to give the filename in         Sub SendEmail(theFileName) or is it a variable to iterate..

Comment: That is a variable, and it is already assigned its value when you call it with the line `SendEmail objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(objFile)`